# Is there a way to open a single screen in a navigator as a modal in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, modal-dialog

I want to open only the TrackTest Screen as a modal from the HomeScreen, I have tried to follow nested navigator docs but I am doing something wrong. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

```
enter code here

import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { WelcomeScreen as WelcomeScreen } from './WelcomeScreen';
import { LoginScreen } from './LoginScreen';
import { SignUpScreen } from './SignUpScreen';
import { ForgotPasswordScreen } from './ForgotPasswordScreen';
import { UserInfoScreen } from './UserInfoScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen'
import { TrackTest } from './TrackScreen';



const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator();

const HomeNavigator = () => (
  <Navigator headerMode='none' 

 >
<Screen name='Welcome' component={WelcomeScreen} />
<Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} />
<Screen name='Forgot' component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
<Screen name='SignUp' component={SignUpScreen} />
<Screen name='UserInfo' component={UserInfoScreen} />
<Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
<Screen name='TrackT' component={TrackTest} />

</Navigator>
);

export const AppNavigator = () => (
<NavigationContainer>
<HomeNavigator />
</NavigationContainer>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/ You can open a screen as a modal as the documentation says by giving `mode="modal"` to the stack navigator.